# Valid syntax of calling pseudo-destructor for a floating constant

Tags: c++, syntax, floating-point, c++17, pseudo-destructor

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef float T;

    0.f.T::~T();
}
```

This program is compiled by `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019`.

But `clang` and `gcc` issue an error like this

```
prog.cc:7:5: error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""f.T'
    7 |     0.f.T::~T();
      |     ^~~~~
```

If to write the expression like `( 0.f ).T::~T()` then all three compilers compile the program.

So a question arises: is this record `0.f.T::~T()` syntactically valid? And if not, then what syntactical rule is broken?

Comment: Putting a space between `0.f` and `.T` causes both GCC and Clang to accept this...

Comment: As well as `(0.f).T::~T();`

Comment: A simple `float f = 1.0f.t;` will produce the error about the numeric literal.

Comment: A `float` is a *built-in* type, it doesn't have a destructor for you to call. What are you even doing manually calling destructors? Outside of placement-new territory, that should be a *big* no-no.

Comment: @JesparJuhl its not a destructor but a pseudo destructor, I just got to know that it exists. The tag info has an example (which also has a not justified call to the destructor btw)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Pseudo or not, valid or not, code like that shouldn't be written (IMHO). *Why* would you do that in any sane application?

Comment: @JesperJuhl The question is about syntactical correctness of this construction.

Comment: @chris It is funny that when I write this 0.f .T::~T() in Visaul C++ then it automatically removes the blank.:)

Comment: I don't see how from https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.fcon and https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext `f.T` can be considered as udl.

Comment: Msvc accepts the code [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/S_5jur). Surprising if only msvc is right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parsing of numerical tokens is quite crude, and allows many things that aren't actually valid numbers. In C++98, the grammar for a "preprocessing number", found in [lex.ppnumber], is

```
pp-number:
    digit
    . digit
    pp-number digit
    pp-number nondigit
    pp-number e sign
    pp-number E sign
    pp-number .
```

Here, a "nondigit" is any character that can be used in an identifier, other than digits, and a "sign" is either + or -. Later standards would expand the definition to allow single quotes (C++14), and sequences of the form p-, p+, P-, P+ (C++17).

The upshot is that, in any version of the standard, while a preprocessing number is required to start with a digit, or a period followed by a digit, after that an arbitrary sequence of digits, letters, and periods may follow. Using the maximal munch rule, it follows that `0.f.T::~T();` is required to be tokenized as `0.f.T :: ~ T ( ) ;`, even though `0.f.T` isn't a valid numerical token.

Thus, the code is **not** syntactically valid.

Comment: Interestingly, there's actually an example with decent similarity in [lex.pptoken]: http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken#5

Answer (score 1):

A user defined literal suffix, *ud-suffix*, is an *identifier*.  An *identifier* is a sequence of letters (including some non-ASCII characters), the underscore, and numbers that does not start with a number.  The period character is not included.

Therefore it is a compiler bug as it is treating the non-identifier sequence `f.T` as an identifier.

The `0.` is a *fractional-constant*, which can be followed by an optional exponent, then either a *ud-suffix* (for a user defined literal) or a *floating-point-suffix* (one of `fFlL`). The `f` can be considered a *ud-suffx* as well, but since it matches another literal type it should be that and not the UDL. A *ud-suffix* is defined in the grammar as an identifier.

Comment: Why is it interpreted as a ud-suffix?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The `0.` is a _fractional-constant_.  That can be followed by (excluding the exponent stuff) a _ud-suffix_ (for a user defined literal) or a _floating-point-suffix_ (one of `fFlL`).  The `f` can be considered a _ud-suffx_ as well, but since it matches another literal type it should be that and not the UDL.  A _ud-suffix_ is defined in the grammar as an _identifier_.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Whereas `f` can be interpreted as ud-suffix,  `f.T` should not as `.`cannot be in identifier. but it is... I would say compiler bug but pretty sure it is more complicated.